# call NodeJs method without load view

Tags: node.js, codeigniter

In my application NodeJs is running on xxx port. Mouse click event trigger node js function using socket.io. My application have real time notification feature.

My Question is

1. Can I trigger nodeJs method when real time notification comes from google
   because, method which handle this notification not load any view ?

Comment: Do you want to push a notification whenever any entry done in your mysql database or you want to push notification from server to node and node to client ?

Comment: @RajJagani I want to push notification from server to node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pushing server to node you can use **redis** for that. you can use a code like below. so for that you need to install redis. you can find installtaion steps on google.

**At your server side for e.g. you are getting the data into your function.**

```
$redisobject = new Redis();
$redisobject->connect('127.0.0.1'); 
$purchase_info = json_encode(array('user_id' =>'2','purchase_information'=>'sample_data')); // json array of data which you want to post
$redisobject->publish('redis_data_php', $purchase_info); //your channel name and data.
```

**Inside your node.js after installing redis module using npm**

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redis_client = redis.createClient();
redis_client.subscribe('redis_data_php'); // same channel name as you have mentioned on php side
redis_client.on('message', function(channel, message){

    var purchase_data = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(purchase_data);
    socket.emit('redis_data', {"info" : purchase_data.purchase_information}); //emit your data to client as you want.
});
```

basically redis will create a channel between php and node.js so you can communicate via that channel.

**Need to install below things**

1. Install redis (if you are using ubuntu than follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis)
2. Than install redis for php (https://joshtronic.com/2014/05/12/how-to-install-phpredis-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/)
3. Install redis for node (**npm install redis**)

Hope this will work for you...